# Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow Displaying Records

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-sqlite

Good day, I was trying to retrieved my data's and display them in a simple way.
Here's my sample code: **SQLiteLocalDatabase .java**

```
public class SQLiteLocalDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private static final String DB_NAME = "project.db";
private static final int VERSION = 1;


public static final String DB_TABLE = " user ";
public static final String ID = " _id ";
public static final String FULL_NAME = " fullname ";
public static final String LOCATION = " location ";
public static final String EMAIL_ADD = " email ";
public static final String PASSWORD = " password ";


public SQLiteLocalDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String queryTable = " CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ FULL_NAME + " TEXT , " + LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + EMAIL_ADD + " TEXT , " + PASSWORD + " TEXT " + " ) ";

    //setUpDb();
    db.execSQL(queryTable);
}

public void setUpDb(){
    //TO OPEN DATABASE - RE-WRITABLE
    sqLiteDatabase  = getWritableDatabase();

}

public void closeTransactionDb(){
    //CLOSE DB IF OPEN
    if(sqLiteDatabase != null && sqLiteDatabase.isOpen()){
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }
}

//INSERT DATA
public long insert(int id,String fullname, String location,String email,String password){

    //CONTENT VALUE contains name-value-pairs
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    if(id != -1) {
        values.put(ID,id);
        values.put(FULL_NAME, fullname);
        values.put(LOCATION, location);
        values.put(EMAIL_ADD, email);
        values.put(PASSWORD, password);
    }
    //Object Table, column, values
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null, values);

}

//UPDATE
public long update(int id, String fullname,String location,String email, String password){
    //CONTENT VALUE contains name-value-pairs
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FULL_NAME,fullname);
        values.put(LOCATION,location);
        values.put(EMAIL_ADD,email);
        values.put(PASSWORD,password);

    //WHERE
        String where = ID + " = " +id;

    //Object Table, values, destination-id
    return sqLiteDatabase.update(DB_TABLE, values, where, null);
}

//DELETE
//
public long delete(int id){
    //WHERE
    String where = ID + " = " +id;

    //Object Table, values, destination-id
    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(DB_TABLE, where, null);
}

public Cursor getAllRecords(){

    String queryDB = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE;
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queryDB, null);
}

public Cursor getSingleRecord(){

    String querySingleRecord = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + "WHERE _id = " +ID;
    return  sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(querySingleRecord,null);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

For my main: **AddItemsActivity .java**

```
public class AddItemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


SQLiteLocalDatabase sqLiteLocalDatabase;

    TextView textViewDbData;
    EditText editTextFullName;
    EditText editTextAddress;
    EditText editTextEmailAdd;
    EditText editTextPassword;
    EditText editTextIDNO;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnUpdate;
    Button btnSearch;
    Button btnDelete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_items);

    sqLiteLocalDatabase = new SQLiteLocalDatabase(AddItemsActivity.this);

    //CALL FUNCTION
    setUpWidgets();
}

public void setUpWidgets(){

    textViewDbData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDbData);
    editTextFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextViewAddFullName);
    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddLocation);
    editTextEmailAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddEmailAddress);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRegPassword);
    editTextIDNO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddID);

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddContacts);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDeleteRecord);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowRecords);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void clearTextFields(){
    editTextFullName.setText("");
    editTextAddress.setText("");
    editTextEmailAdd.setText("");
    editTextPassword.setText("");
    editTextIDNO.setText("");

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String fullName = editTextFullName.getText().toString().trim();
    String location = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();
    String emailAdd = editTextEmailAdd.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();


    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonAddContacts:
            //IF result == -1
            long result = sqLiteLocalDatabase.insert(Integer.parseInt(getValue(editTextIDNO)), fullName, location, emailAdd, password);
            if(result == -1){
                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Error: Someone own that Id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Success Id: " +result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                clearTextFields();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.buttonUpdate:

            if(editTextIDNO.getText().equals("")){

                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Please Enter User ID  ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else {

                long update = sqLiteLocalDatabase.update(Integer.parseInt(getValue(editTextIDNO)),
                        getValue(editTextFullName),
                        getValue(editTextAddress),
                        getValue(editTextEmailAdd),
                        getValue(editTextPassword)
                );

                if (update == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Error Updating ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (update == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Successfully Modified", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    clearTextFields();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Error All data updated Id: " + update, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;

        case R.id.buttonDeleteRecord:

            long delete = sqLiteLocalDatabase.delete(Integer.parseInt(getValue(editTextIDNO)));
            if(delete == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Error Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Success Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                clearTextFields();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.buttonShowRecords:

            StringBuffer finalData = new StringBuffer();
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteLocalDatabase.getAllRecords();

            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext() ){

                finalData.append(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.ID)));
                finalData.append(" - ");

                finalData.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.FULL_NAME)));
                finalData.append(" - ");

                finalData.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.LOCATION)));
                finalData.append(" - ");

                finalData.append(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.EMAIL_ADD)));
                finalData.append(" - ");

                finalData.append(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.PASSWORD)));
                finalData.append("\n");

            }
            textViewDbData.setText(finalData);
            break;
    }
}

public String getValue(EditText editText){
    return  editText.getText().toString().trim();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    sqLiteLocalDatabase.setUpDb();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    sqLiteLocalDatabase.closeTransactionDb();
}
```

My problem was with the getAllRecords in the append part.
Logcat:

[image: Logcat - Debug]

Comment: make sure the cursor contains all the columns you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is because one of the method of getting column index like `cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.ID)` returns -1.

Make sure the `Cursor` contains all the columns you are retrieving and check if `getColumnIndex` method is not returning `-1`.

```
if(cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.ID) != -1) {
    finalData.append(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.ID)));
    finalData.append(" - ");
}
```

Likewise check all conditions.

Hope it'll work.

Comment: How to do that? I mean I called them individually. ID, FULLNAME, LOCATION, EMAIL_ADD, PASSWORD.

Comment: add the `if(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME) != -1)` condition before getting record in `for` loop, i added example how to do that.

Comment: I followed the solution. :) It will not now produce an error. But no data displayed. :(

 if(cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.ID) != -1 && cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.FULL_NAME) != -1 && cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.LOCATION) != -1 &&
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.LOCATION) != -1 && cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.EMAIL_ADD) != -1 && cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.PASSWORD) != -1) {

Comment: you did it wrong..you've to check each condition in its own `if()` block.

Comment: Is this right?

 if(cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.ID) != -1) {
                    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext() ){
                        finalData.append(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(sqLiteLocalDatabase.ID)));
                        finalData.append(" - ");
                    }
                }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105492/discussion-between-elite-and-rock).